# How to pass an enum value to a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, enums

```
protected enum Category { Action, Fiction, Drama, Romance, SciFi, Poems, Kids }
```

I have created this `enum` type, and now I have to make a constructor for my class.

```
public Book(String title, int code, List<String> authors, String publisher, int year, Category categ){
        this.title = title;
        this.code = code;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.year = year;
        this.category = ....;
}
```

I don't understand how I will pass to the constructor the value of the enumerated type.

Can anyone help?

I know it's beginners question, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this

```
new Book( title, ........ ,Category.anyEnumConstant);
```

For ex:

```
   Book book=  new Book( title, ........ ,Category.Fiction);
```

Then inside the constructor

```
 this.category = categ;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either send the enum as such or send a String and use the valueOf() to get the Enum.

**Solution 1:** Send the enum as such.

```
new Book(title, code, authors, publisher, year, Category.Action);
```

and in your constructor,

```
public Book(String title, int code, List<String> authors, String publisher, int year, Category categ){
    ...
    this.category = categ;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Send a string value and use the `valueOf()` to get the enum from it.

```
new Book(title, code, authors, publisher, year, "Action");
```

and in your constructor,

```
public Book(String title, int code, List<String> authors, String publisher, int year, String categString){
    ....
    this.category = Category.valueOf(categString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Book(String title, int code, List<String> authors, String publisher, int year, Category categ){
        // ...
        this.category = categ;
}
```

Then call

```
new Book(/* ... */, Category.Action)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple assignment of enum Constant value to a enum variable.

```
String title= "somevalue";
int code = 1;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String publisher = "somevalue";
int year=2013;
Category categ = Category.Action;
Book book = new Book(title, code, arrayList, publisher, year, categ);
```

In Enums we just use the enums Object Constants declared in Enum declaration.
Actually they are the objects of your enum.
here is a link where you can find a simple example to explore enums.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

and in Constructor declaration you just simply have to assign the value like other variables.

```
this.category = categ;
```