# JAVA constructor not accepting enum values

Tags: java, oop, enums

Tried this code to learn functional Java but my Person constructor not accepting enum values, giving a compilation error and is not taking named parameters gving syntax error. Kindly poit to the error I am making.

```
 package imperative;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = List.of(
                    new Person(name:"John",MALE),
                    new Person(name:"Alexa",FEMALE),
                    new Person(name:"Sam",MALE),
                    new Person(name:"Maria",FEMALE),
                    new Person(name:"Drake",MALE)
                );
    }
    class Person{
        private final String name;
        private final Gender gender;
        public Person(String name, Gender gender) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
        }
    }
        enum Gender{
            MALE,FEMALE
        }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an enum value to a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069410/how-to-pass-an-enum-value-to-a-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code compiles:

```
package imperative;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static String name;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = List.of(
                    new Person("John",Gender.MALE),
                    new Person("Alexa",Gender.FEMALE),
                    new Person("Sam",Gender.MALE),
                    new Person("Maria",Gender.FEMALE),
                    new Person("Drake",Gender.MALE)
                );
    }
    static class Person{
        private final String name;
        private final Gender gender;
        public Person(String name, Gender gender) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + "]";
        }
    }
        enum Gender{
            MALE,FEMALE
        }
    
}
```

It was necessary to fully qualify MALE and FEMALE and pass the name as a string: no need to use the syntax

```
name: "John"
```

Comment: yeah but still wondering why "name:" is not working

Comment: Your constructor is accepting as input a String and an instance of Gender.
The syntax name: "John" is not valid in Java.

Comment: This won't compile. The `Person` class should be declared **static**.

Comment: @Marco Actually found this syntax in a video tutorial

Comment: @SamratDas, interesting. It is possible that is a new syntax and I am not aware of. Let me see.

Comment: How can a non-static instance of Person be instantiated without any instance of Main?

Comment: Fixed it :). You are right.

Comment: @SamratDas can you link the video? Java doesn’t support named parameters at the call site.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make your class `Person` static, as you're using it in a static method:

```
static class Person {
```

Then use qualified enum values like `Gender.MALE` or `Gender.FEMALE`.
Finally invoke the constructor as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> people = List.of(
            new Person("John", Gender.MALE),
            new Person("Alexa", Gender.FEMALE),
            new Person("Sam", Gender.MALE),
            new Person("Maria", Gender.FEMALE),
            new Person("Drake", Gender.MALE)
    );
}
```

Comment: enum issue solved still facing ":" invalid operator error..Can you help?

Comment: @SamratDas Did you try to run my code? I removed the `name: ` parts as well.